# How to determine if I'm in powershell or cmd?

Tags: powershell, ssh, cmd, openssh

I've been playing with [OpenSSH on Windows](https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH) and it looks like the normal Unix aliases are missing. I'm not sure whether it's starting powershell or cmd when I log in to a Windows machine via SSH. What's the correct way to see the currently running shell on Windows?

Comment: ``(dir 2>&1 *`|echo CMD);&<# rem #>echo PowerShell``

Comment: Curious what the best answer could be. I would think this one could be tough looking for a "clean" way to do it. I mean while you are at it you could also ask to see if you are running in ruby or python as well. PowerShell and cmd are not really at all comparable. PowerShell is .net based and its similarities to cmd are there to ease the transition for people that used to use cmd batch

Comment: @PetSerAl This doesn't work if the profile redefines `dir` to invoke cmd.exe's dir command (which my profile does). But it's pretty clever nonetheless.

Comment: @user2460798 Hope you does not redefine `type` or `echo`: `(type 2>&1 -ea ig .|echo CMD);&<# rem #>echo PowerShell`

Answer (score 29, accepted):

All credit goes to [PetSerAl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4003407/petseral), this had to be posted as an aswer:

```
(dir 2>&1 *`|echo CMD);&<# rem #>echo PowerShell
```

Within `Win32-OpenSSH` this command also works, and outputs `CMD`.

NB : `Win32-OpenSSH` seems a bit limited, `cd` is not recognized on my system.

Comment: Sadly this trick doesn't work with PowerShell 6+, if one wanted to detect whether it's powershell.exe or pwsh.exe :(

Comment: Can't I just execute a Powershell specific command, If it's working then it's Powershell else CMD? like `$PROFILE` or `ls`

Comment: @marcus Ottoson: but works on PoweShell 7.1.5

Answer (score 12):

I'd like to expand on @sodawillow's answer to also distinguish between using *Powershell* (**powershell.exe**) known as `Desktop` and *PWSH* (**pwsh.exe**) known as `Core`.

```
(dir 2>&1 *`|echo CMD);&<# rem #>echo ($PSVersionTable).PSEdition
# Returns one of: CMD, Core, Desktop
```

This works in all instances where a sub-shell is **not** instantiated. What that means is that it **does not work** from opening a default sub-process in Python, as it always uses **CMD** when interacting with windows. This is actually set by the Windows environment variable: `ComSpec` always pointing to `C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe`.

For example:

(Starting the python interpreter from a pwsh shell.)

```py
>>> import os, subprocess
>>> c="(dir 2>&1 *`|echo CMD);&<# rem #>echo($PSVersionTable).PSEdition"
>>> subprocess.call(c,shell=True)
CMD
```

For other Python shell detection schemes, please see [this good post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55598796/1147688).

---

**UPDATE: 2020-05-01**

I managed to get the above working, but with the obnoxious side effect of **always** loading the powershell *profile*, before executing. The trick was to specify `execute=<path-to-powershell-exe>` like this:

(Start a python CLI.)

```py
import os, subprocess
c="(dir 2>&1 *`|echo CMD);&<# rem #>echo($PSVersionTable).PSEdition"
e="C:\\Windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe"
subprocess.call(c, shell=True, executable=e)

# output:
# <blah blah from profile>
# Desktop
# 0
```

I have not been able to circumvent the powershell profile issue. But [apparently](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45090774/1147688) it is something being worked on. See [here](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/3743) and [here](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/pull/3558).

Comment: Great answer! Note 'core' isn't a thing anymore since Powershell 7. It's just 'Windows Powershell' and 'Powershell'.

Comment: @mikemaccana Interesting, and perhaps good. But it still returns "Core"...

Comment: @mikemaccana I managed to get a step further, but I'm not able to avoid loading the *profile*. There is also a mysterious `0` at the very end of the output.