# Python Popen fails in compound command (PowerShell)

Tags: python, powershell, subprocess, popen

I am trying to use Python's Popen to change my working directory and execute a command.

```
pg = subprocess.Popen("cd c:/mydirectory ; ./runExecutable.exe --help", stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, shell=True)
buff,buffErr = pg.communicate()
```

However, powershell returns "The system cannot find the path specified." The path **does** exist.

If I run

```
 pg = subprocess.Popen("cd c:/mydirectory ;", stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, shell=True)
```

it returns the same thing.

However, if i run this: (without the semicolon)

```
pg = subprocess.Popen("cd c:/mydirectory",stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, shell=True)
```

The command returns without an error. This leads me to believe that the semicolon is issue. What is the cause for this behavior and how can I get around it?

*I know I can just do c:/mydirectory/runExecutable.exe --help, but I would like to know why this is happening.*

**UPDATE :**

I have tested passing the path to powershell as the argument for Popen's `executable` parameter. Just `powershell.exe` may not be enough. To find the true absolute path of `powershell`, execute `where.exe powershell`. Then you can pass it into Popen. Note that `shell` is still true. It will use the default shell but pass the command to `powershell.exe`

```
powershell = C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe
pg = subprocess.Popen("cd c:/mydirectory ; ./runExecutable.exe", stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, shell=True, executable=powershell)
buff,buffErr = pg.communicate()
//It works!
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your `subprocess.Popen()` call, `shell=True` means that the platform's *default* shell should be used.

While the Windows world is - commendably - moving from CMD (`cmd.exe`) to PowerShell, **Python determines what shell to invoke based on the `COMSPEC` environment variable**, which **still points to `cmd.exe`**, even in the latest W10 update that has moved toward PowerShell in terms of what the *GUI* offers as the default shell.

For backward compatibility, this will not change anytime soon, and will possibly never change.

Therefore, your **choices** are:

- Use `cmd` syntax, as suggested in [Maurice Meyer's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45090650/45375) answer.
- **Do *not* use `shell = True` and invoke `powershell.exe` *explicitly*** - see below.
- *Windows only*: Redefine environment variable `COMSPEC` before using `shell = True` - see below.

---

A simple Python example of how to invoke the `powershell` binary directly, with command-line switches followed by a single string containing the PowerShell source code to execute:

```
import subprocess

args = 'powershell', '-noprofile', '-command', 'set-location /; $pwd'
subprocess.Popen(args)
```

Note that I've deliberately used `powershell` instead of `powershell.exe`, because that opens up the possibility of the command working on *Unix* platforms too, once [PowerShell *Core*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell) is released.

---

*Windows only*: An example with `shell = True`, after redefining environment variable `COMSPEC` to point to PowerShell first:

```
import os, subprocess    

os.environ["COMSPEC"] = 'powershell'

subprocess.Popen('Set-Location /; $pwd', shell=True)
```

Note:

- `COMSPEC` is only consulted on *Windows*; on Unix platforms, the shell executable is *invariably* `/bin/sh`
- As of Windows PowerShell v5.1 / PowerShell Core v6-beta.3, invoking `powershell` with just `-c` (interpreted as `-Command`) still loads the profiles files *by default*, which can have unexpected side effects (with the explicit invocation of `powershell` used above, `-noprofile` suppresses that).

  - Changing the default behavior to *not* loading the profiles is the subject of this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/3743), in an effort to align PowerShell's CLI with that of POSIX-like shells.

Comment: I'm trying to use *powershell* as the default python OS shell, but it always load the profile. Is there a work around how to do both; using python's `executable=<path-to-powershell-exe>` **and** using the `-NoProfile` argument? As an option, perhaps one can manipulate the env variable `ComSpec`? But IDK if that helps, because maybe then the entire environment is lost?

Comment: @not2qubit `ComSpec` is expected to contain an executable-file path only, so you wouldn't be able to specify `-NoProfile`. Not sure what you mean by environment being lost.

Comment: Aha, ok. I meant that modding ComSpec might influence subsequent calls. I.e. If I set ComSpec somewhere in Py script, then any subsequent os calls would still have that, or does it get reset upon a new `subprocess.Popen()` call, when specifying a different `executable`? (I guess it doesn't.) BTW. I am asking all this, because of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61469226/1147688).

Comment: @not2qubit Yes, any subsequent `subprocess.Popen()` call with `shell = true` will be affected and more generally, any child process will see the modified `ComSpec` value. You could localize the modification (restore the original value after a call), but that seems hardly worth it (and it assumes that no child-process-creating code runs in parallel while the modified value is in effect).

Answer (score 0):

You can concat multiple commands using '&' character instead of a semicolon. Try this:

```
pg = subprocess.Popen("cd c:/mydirectory & ./runExecutable.exe --help", stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, shell=True)
buff,buffErr = pg.communicate()
```