# Running Powershell Commands through Python script not working (ex: Set-Location (change directory))

Tags: python, powershell

I currently have the following code under `C:\Users\MyName\Desktop\test.py`

```
import subprocess
command='Set-Location new_folder'
subprocess.Popen('powershell -command '+"'"+command+"'", shell=True)
```

What I want this to do is for the

```
1. "Set-Location new_folder" to be written
2. And the 'Set-Location new_folder' command is executed and the currently directory is set to new_folder, such as "C:\Users\MyName\Desktop\new_folder"
```

However, this is not so and just the words are inputted and doesn't react, like the picture below:
[image]

It can be seen that the one above is not colored in yellow, and the one below is colored in yellow. The yellow one is the one I hand-coded "Set-Location new_folder", which actually works and changes the directory to the new_folder. The above one which is not colored in yellow is when I executed from the python script, and the powershell doesn't recognize it as a command...

How to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Read the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe?view=powershell-5.1#-command), especially this part:

> In `cmd.exe`, there is no such thing as a script block (or **ScriptBlock**
> type), so the value passed to **Command** will always be a string. You can
> write a script block inside the string, but instead of being executed
> it will behave exactly as though you typed it at a typical PowerShell
> prompt, printing the contents of the script block back out to you.
>
> A string passed to **Command** is still executed as PowerShell code, so
> the script block curly braces are often not required in the first
> place when running from `cmd.exe`. To execute an inline script block
> defined inside a string, the [call operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-5.1#special-operators) `&` can be used:
>
> ```
> powershell.exe -Command "& {Get-WinEvent -LogName security}"
> ```
>
> If the value of **Command** is a string, **Command** must be the last
> parameter for pwsh, because all arguments following it are interpreted
> as part of the command to execute.

As you are calling PowerShell from Python, you have to use the above mentioned syntax. Furthermore:

- You don't need `shell=True` in your case ([details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45090774/11942268))
- The [`Popen` constructor](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor) expects a list of arguments, not a string.

So, change your PowerShell call to the following line:

```
subprocess.Popen(['powershell', '-Command', '& {'+command+'}'])
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but it still doesn't work... I can't find out why...

Comment: @SihwanLee Does the update help? It works on my machine...