# How to get type of hosting window from inside Python?

Tags: python, shell, cmd, terminal, console

I would like to know which window is hosting the terminal running Python. In specific, I would like to distinguish between `windows terminal` and the old `CMD` console on Windows machine.

EDIT:
I'm not sure I'm using correct words and there is an overload of words anyway. To be more specifc, I want to know the `host window` becaue they have different behaviours. Here's a photo of different windows, one of which `Windows Terminal`. `powershell` or `cmd` can be run in either of the windows, I'm interested in figuring out that window host.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to determine if I'm in powershell or cmd?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34471956/how-to-determine-if-im-in-powershell-or-cmd)

Answer (score 0):

If you use the psutil and os packages, you can use

```py
parent_pid = os.getppid()
print(psutil.Process(parent_pid).name())
```

to get the parent process' name.

Comment: got this output `ipython.exe` on both terminals. I'm interested in the hosting shell. Could it be that IPython who knows this?

Comment: @AlexDeft This is because you're running the program with ipython, and not directly from the cmd or powershell. Can't really help any further because I dont use windows.

Comment: Hmmm, do you want me to run it from terminal itself? then yes, it works. I just tried it `python -c "import os;import psutil;print(psutil.Process(os.getppid()).name())"`got `pwsh`. Should I modify my question to highlight IPython?

Comment: please have a look at the modified quetstion

Answer (score 0):

You could query `WMI` as I prefer to use OS tools (should work with `psutil` aswell, as mentioned by [@BaguetteYeeter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15044559/baguetteyeeter)):

```
import os
import subprocess
import sys

print("Python interpreter: %s" % sys.executable)
parentShellName = None
# root process to look for parents until we find a process name
# which has not python in it's name
parentPid = os.getpid()

while 1:
    # In case of ipython the second parent process is the Shell, so we are looping!
    # Probably there should be a counter to finish the while loop in case no shell could be detected!
    cmd = 'wmic process where "ProcessId=%s" get parentprocessid /format:list' % parentPid
    proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
    out, err = proc.communicate()
    key, parentPid = out.strip().decode('utf-8').split('=')

    print("Parent ProcessId: %s" % parentPid)

    cmd2 = 'wmic process where "ProcessId=%s" get name /format:list' % parentPid
    proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd2, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
    out, err = proc.communicate()
    key, parentShellName = out.strip().decode('utf-8').split('=')

    if 'python' not in parentShellName.lower():
        break

print(parentShellName)
```

Out:

[image]